# Rating button filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]

I'm trying to filtering my list from bad to excellent like trivago system

[if you are going to click this link](https://www.trivago.com.tr/?cpt=3481203&iRoomType=7&iPathId=34812&aDateRange%5Barr%5D=2017-05-14&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=2017-05-15&iGeoDistanceItem=0&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&)
 you will understand what I'm talking about and I show section on image what I want to do.

When you click button you see styling is removing or adding again and showing hotel list I really didn't understand how to do that ? is there any example

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#wrap {
  width: 960px;
}

#wrap:before,
#wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#filter {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 59%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.filter-list {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main id="wrap">

  <div id="filter">
    <button class="bad" data-id="1" style="background:#cc0033;color:#fff" name="rating">bad</button>
    <button class="normal" data-id="2" style="background:orange;color:#fff" name="rating">normal</button>
    <button class="good" data-id="3" style="background:#99cc00;color:#fff" name="rating">good</button>
    <button class="verygood" data-id="4" style="background:green;color:#fff" name="rating">very good</button>
    <button class="excellent" data-id="5" style="background:darkgreen;color:#fff" name="rating">excellent</button>
  </div>
  <!-- filter-->

  <div id="content">
    <div class="filter-list">
      I'm a very good
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      this is the bad list
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      I'm a very good to
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Excellent!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Iııh normal!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Good - enough thanks
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Bad - don't ever..
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Excellent again
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      isn't bad ? I think yes bad..
    </div>
  </div>


</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code its working like on the trivago page!

```js
$("button").on("click", function (){
  $(this).css("opacity", "1");
  $(this).nextAll().css("opacity", "1");
  $(this).prevAll().css("opacity", "0.5");
});
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#wrap {
  width: 960px;
}

#wrap:before,
#wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

#filter {
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 59%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.filter-list {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<main id="wrap">

  <div id="filter">
    <button class="bad" data-id="1" style="background:#cc0033;color:#fff" name="rating">bad</button>
    <button class="normal" data-id="2" style="background:orange;color:#fff" name="rating">normal</button>
    <button class="good" data-id="3" style="background:#99cc00;color:#fff" name="rating">good</button>
    <button class="verygood" data-id="4" style="background:green;color:#fff" name="rating">very good</button>
    <button class="excellent" data-id="5" style="background:darkgreen;color:#fff" name="rating">excellent</button>
  </div>
  <!-- filter-->

  <div id="content">
    <div class="filter-list">
      I'm a very good
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      this is the bad list
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      I'm a very good to
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Excellent!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Iııh normal!
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Good - enough thanks
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Bad - don't ever..
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      Excellent again
    </div>
    <div class="filter-list">
      isn't bad ? I think yes bad..
    </div>
  </div>


</main>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jQuery is needed btw! You already included it in your snippet.

Comment: @recruit_man Do you need the section filter also?